# Slideshow Images Not Fitting The Whole Page?

Tags: html, image, slideshow

I created a slideshow using HTML and CSS. Everything works, but the images don't take up the full page. Here's what this looks like:

[image]

Comment: Link is not working...

Comment: you have a email? i can email you the image and all, i need to figure this out by today..

Comment: Would help if you uploaded it to a web server so we can inspect the HTML.

Comment: How do i do that? ...

Comment: This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed. You are invited to read http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

from the looks of your screenshot you have some padding and margin on the body and/or html tags.
But a link would work best in your favor.